# Thread creation in loop

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

I am trying to perform multi writer program, in which each writer thread acquires the lock of a queue one by one and then multiple readers read it. The following code is working fine for 1st writer but it is not giving desired output for second writer own wards actually writer thread function is not getting called after first iteration. kindly help..

```
for(i = 0; i < wno; i++)
{   
    fflush(stdin);
    ret = pthread_create(&writter[i], NULL, write_to_queue, NULL);
    if( ret != 0)
    {
        printf("Could not create Thread \n");
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        sleep(10);
        printf("Value of ret %d\n", ret);
        for(j = 0; j < rno; j++)
        {
            pthread_create(&reader[t], NULL, read_from_queue, NULL);
            //sleep(2);
            t++;
        }
        sleep(1);
    }

void *write_to_queue()
{
int ch;

pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
while(ch != 0)
{
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Choose one of the following to proceed\nPress 1 to EnQueue\nPress 2 to DeQueue\nPress 0 to Exit\n");
    scanf("%d", &ch);
    getchar();
    switch(ch)
    {
        case 0      :   ch = 0; break;
        case 1      :   EnQueue(); break;
        case 2      :   DeQueue(); break;
        default :   printf("Please Enter a valid Choice\n"); break;
    }   
}
pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

reader threads are working fine.

Comment: have you tried using `pthread_rwlock`

Comment: The answer provided below is working, i misplaced the lock and unlock statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `lock` is acquired before entering the loop, and only released after leaving the loop.

If you want the threads to contend on each iteration, move the acquire and release calls to be inside the loop. Note that your code had undefined behavior from reading `ch` uninitialized. The code below fixes that.

```
int ch = -1;       // Initialize!

while (ch != 0) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    printf("%s",
        "Choose one of the following to proceed\n"
        "Press 1 to EnQueue\n"
        "Press 2 to DeQueue\n"
        "Press 0 to Exit\n");
    scanf("%d", &ch);
    getchar();
    switch(ch) {
    case 0  :   ch = 0; break;
    case 1  :   EnQueue(); break;
    case 2  :   DeQueue(); break;
    default :   printf("Please Enter a valid Choice\n"); break;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}
```

As a matter of multithread programming design, you should avoid "fat lock syndrome". A *fat lock* is one that serializes execution on a very large segment of the thread's code in such a way that it practically removes any parallel execution in the program.

To achieve parallelism, a more granular approach to safeguard critical sections should be used. This means that the lock acquisition and release is isolated to just the portion of the code that require it. This typically means the manipulations of a particular shared data structure, and in your case, it would be the `EnQueue` and `DeQueue` operations.

Your particular program seems to be I/O heavy. Unfortunately, accessing `stdin` and `stdout` have to be treated as critical sections if you want consistent I/O behavior. However, you may consider creating a separate I/O thread that can interact with `stdin` and `stdout` without need of a lock. The choice can be placed on a work queue, and worker threads can be waiting on the work queue to perform the work. As each thread processes the requested work, it can perform granular locks as needed to complete the work.

Comment: More specifically, before and after the EnQueue(); call.  No larger scope!

Comment: still giving the same output

Comment: @MartinJames: `scanf` and `getchar` from two simultaneous threads might be confusing.

Comment: I don't understand what you did when you said *tried it, still not working*. What didn't work?

Comment: I placed the lock unlock exactly as you have done it din't work, but when i copied your code, it worked.

Comment: Then, it looks like not initializing `ch` also caused issues for you.

Comment: @AbhayRawat please do accept the answer if it worked for you